# Error running TestNG under Eclipse "not a supported TestNG version"

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

I have my Maven Project set up in Eclipse Kepler. The pom.xml file has a dependency on TestNg 6.0.1. When I right-click on my project, it displays the option "Run as TestNG". But when i click on it, Eclipse shows an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException: 
6.0.1 is not a supported TestNG version
  at org.testng.remote.support.ServiceLoaderHelper.getFirst(ServiceLoaderHelper.java:22)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:43)
```

Dependency in POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the latest version of TestNG as a dependency in your POM.

Probably your Eclipse plugin for TestNG is up to date, and the TestNG version used as the POM dependency is too old.  Try with [6.9.10](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng)

Comment: 6.9.11 is available too